# calling local variable in later function

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to delete a post. There is a modal that asks if you want to delete or not. Below is my script. The issue I am having is that I cannot get my variable postID to be used in my function where the ajax is called. I know this is an issue of my postID variable being a local variable. How can I use that variable so that it can be called in a later function. I thought of making it global, but when i tried to do so it did not work. (Where '+' occur is due to this script being echoed out by php)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    bindFunc()
        $('.creatorPostOptions').click(function(){
        var postID = $(this).val();
            $('.postOptionsFull').show();
            $('.postOptionsFullContent').append('<button id='+'editPostButton'+'>Edit</button><button id='+'deletePostButton'+' value='+''+'>Delete</button><button id='+'cancelPostButton'+'>Cancel</button>');
            bindFunc();
        });
        function bindFunc() {
            $('#cancelPostButton').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsFull').hide();
                $('.postOptionsFullContent').children('button').remove();
            });
            $('#deletePostButton').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsFullContent').hide();
                $('.deletePostConfirmation').show();
                $('.deletePostButtons').append('<button id='+'cancelDeletePost'+'>Cancel</button><button id='+'deletePost'+'>Delete</button>');
                deletePostFunction();
            });
        }
        function deletePostFunction() {
            $('#cancelDeletePost').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsFullContent').show();
                $('.deletePostConfirmation').hide();
                $('.deletePostButtons').children('button').remove();
            });
            $('#deletePost').click(function(){
            var postID = postID;
                $.ajax({
                    url: deletePost.php,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:{postID:postID},
                    success:function(data){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        $('.noncreatorPostOptions').click(function(){
            $('.postOptionsPartial').show();
            $('.postOptionsPartialContent').append('<button id='+'reportPostButton'+'>Report</button><button id='+'cancelReportButton'+'>Cancel</button>');
            bindFuncTwo();
        });
        function bindFuncTwo() {
            $('#cancelReportButton').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsPartial').hide();
                $('.postOptionsPartialContent').children('button').remove();
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Think you should replace the `PHP` tag with `jquery`.

Comment: Are you talking about a postID from, say, wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to define the var outside the function?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var postID;
    bindFunc()
        $('.creatorPostOptions').click(function(){
            postID = $(this).val();
            $('.postOptionsFull').show();
            $('.postOptionsFullContent').append('<button id='+'editPostButton'+'>Edit</button><button id='+'deletePostButton'+' value='+''+'>Delete</button><button id='+'cancelPostButton'+'>Cancel</button>');
            bindFunc();
        });
        function bindFunc() {
            $('#cancelPostButton').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsFull').hide();
                $('.postOptionsFullContent').children('button').remove();
            });
            $('#deletePostButton').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsFullContent').hide();
                $('.deletePostConfirmation').show();
                $('.deletePostButtons').append('<button id='+'cancelDeletePost'+'>Cancel</button><button id='+'deletePost'+'>Delete</button>');
                deletePostFunction();
            });
        }
        function deletePostFunction() {
            $('#cancelDeletePost').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsFullContent').show();
                $('.deletePostConfirmation').hide();
                $('.deletePostButtons').children('button').remove();
            });
            $('#deletePost').click(function(){
                postID = postID;
                $.ajax({
                    url: deletePost.php,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:{postID:postID},
                    success:function(data){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        $('.noncreatorPostOptions').click(function(){
            $('.postOptionsPartial').show();
            $('.postOptionsPartialContent').append('<button id='+'reportPostButton'+'>Report</button><button id='+'cancelReportButton'+'>Cancel</button>');
            bindFuncTwo();
        });
        function bindFuncTwo() {
            $('#cancelReportButton').click(function(){
                $('.postOptionsPartial').hide();
                $('.postOptionsPartialContent').children('button').remove();
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: haha im dumb I was trying to define the variable and set it to $(this).val() outside of the function..thank you for taking the time to help me out

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a function scoped language, not a block scoped language like PHP. When you initialize the variable  postID  inside of the click handler function for '.creatorPostOptions', it is not accessible outside of that click handler.

You can define the variable (and assign its value) outside of the click handle for .creatorPostOptions as suggested by @GavinLuo. However, I'm not sure I understand why the id of said post would be set to $(this).val(). Shouldn't its ID be represented in the DOM by an HTML ID attribute?